# NodeJS Promises VS async library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently working on a NodeJS server, and am switching from callbacks to promises.

Here's an example of my code:

```
 var record = req.body.record;
var schoolId = req.body.schoolId;
var promise = BusController.addBus(record,schoolId);
promise.then(function(){
    return res.json({status:"success", message : "bus successfully created"});
}).catch(function(error){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.json({status:"error",message:"error while creating bus"});
            return;
        }
```

The bus controller has the following in it:

```
addBus : function(record,schoold){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var bus_number = record.bus_number;

        var newBus = new Bus({
            language: language ? language : "",
            bus_number: bus_number  ? bus_number : "",
            bus_driver: bus_driver  ? bus_driver : {},
            bus_details: bus_details ,
            trips: trips ? trips : [],
            school_id: schoold,
            location: location ? location : {}
        });
        newBus.save().then(function(bus){
            var busCreation = {};
            busCreation.name=  "باص رقم"+ ' ' +bus_number;
            busCreation.type= "3";
            busCreation.refid= bus._id;
            busCreation.email= record.email;
            busCreation.phone_number=record.phone_number;
            busCreation.school_id = schoold;
            console.log(busCreation);
            var promise = UserController.addUser(busCreation);
            promise.then(function(){
                resolve();
            })
        }).catch(function(error){
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This my current logic. Is this a good practice? Or should I switch to async library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That bus controller is too complicated; in general you should not be using `new Promise(fn)` unless you are wrapping a callback, and what you're doing is better done by returning a promise from the `.then()`. (When you return a value from `myPromise.then()` it gets passed into `Promise.resolve(p)`, which if `p` is not a promise creates a new one which immediately resolves with the value you created; or if `p` is a promise, just returns that promise.)

In addition I wouldn't mix camelCase and underscore_names; it leads to bigger confusions across the codebase. In addition the form `a ? a : b` is equivalent to the shorter `a || b`. I also would in general add a debugging string to any `console.log` so that while you're in development you can better drill down to exactly what you're looking for.

With those changes the bus controller simplifies to just:

```js
addBus: function(record, schoold) {
    return new Bus({
        language: language || "",
        bus_number: record.bus_number || "",
        bus_driver: bus_driver  || {},
        bus_details: bus_details,
        trips: trips || [],
        school_id: schoold,
        location: location || {}
    }).save().then(function (bus) {
        var bus_creation_user = {
            name: "باص رقم" + ' ' + record.bus_number,
            type: "3",
            refid: bus._id,
            email: record.email,
            phone_number: record.phone_number,
            school_id: schoold
        };
        console.log("bus_creation_user", bus_creation_user);
        return UserController.addUser(bus_creation_user);
    });
});
```

The code for using it seems mostly fine but has some code smells. For example what is the `if` doing in your `.catch(err => { if (err) { ... } })`? Are you legitimately throwing non-Error objects like `null` and `undefined` and `false`? (In JS you can do this but it is widely considered to be a bad idea.) Instead you can just write,

```js
BusController.addBus(record, schoolId).then(function(){
    res.json({status:"success", message: "bus successfully created"});
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
    res.json({status:"error", message: "error while creating bus"});
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, what you say makes sense and helped a lot

Comment: but in general what is better, async or promises?

Comment: "async" and "await" are syntactic sugar for handling Promises. There is no difference, use `async function` and `await` if you have them. You might instead be asking whether Promises are better than callbacks, Node's general function types being `([Value], Either Error Value -> IO ()) -> IO()` and promise-returning functions instead being `[Value] -> IO (Either Error Value)`. They are, with the biggest reason being that it is easy to lose track of an error thrown in callback code, and a minor reason being that this `Promise.resolve` semantics de-nestifies weakly-interdependent code.

Comment: Code with strong interdependencies between promises can also be de-nested, but you need to hand around all of your state values as arguments because you can't capture them in the inner closure and you might not want the quasi-global null-by-default Smaaktics of putting them in an outer closure.